# Impossible to build app ionic on android

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I've been working on a project with ionic from a long time.

Recently i updated android studio and it's packages and now i can't build on android anymore because of the following issue:

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   com/google/android/gms/iid/zzc.class

Before updating android studio everything worked well.

This is a ionic v1 app with cordova android engine 6.1.2.

I'm using cordova 6.5.0, ionic 2.2.1.

My android environment: sdk tools 25.2.3, sdk platform tools 26, sdk build tools 26

Do you have any idea why i keep getting this error when compiling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is being caused by conflicting versions of the Play Services library being requested by different plugins.

Quickest way to fix is to install [cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release) into your Cordova project which will force Gradle to align the versions:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release
```