# Facing trouble after add firebase to my cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, admob

When I build android from my cmd. Then it displayed the following msg as below. How to solve it?:

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.

  > Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#com.google.android.gms.version@value value=(8115000) from AndroidManifest.xml:24:66-89
  >       is also present at [com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.2] AndroidManifest.xml:23:13-66 value=(@integer/google_play_services_version).
  >       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-92 to override.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
  D:\phoneGap\tatkaKhabor\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml:24:66-89 Error:
      Attribute meta-data#com.google.android.gms.version@value value=(8115000) from AndroidManifest.xml:24:66-89
      is also present at [com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.2] AndroidManifest.xml:23:13-66 value=(@integer/google_play_services_version).
      Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-92 to override.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.

  > Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#com.google.android.gms.version@value value=(8115000) from AndroidManifest.xml:24:66-89
  >       is also present at [com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.2] AndroidManifest.xml:23:13-66 value=(@integer/google_play_services_version).
  >       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-92 to override.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"

Comment: See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44759306/777265) - you have the same problem (Play Services version conflict) and the same solution will work.